# TypeError: get_tracer() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, flask, open-telemetry

I'm trying to set up OpenTelemetry so I can gather some traces for a Flask app and I'm running into an error with the instrument_app() method from opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask. This is what my __init__.py up to the error looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from .config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from prometheus_flask_exporter import PrometheusMetrics
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.flask import FlaskInstrumentor 
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.requests import RequestsInstrumentor
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import (
    BatchSpanProcessor,
    ConsoleSpanExporter,
)


trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(
    BatchSpanProcessor(ConsoleSpanExporter())
)

app = Flask(__name__)

FlaskInstrumentor().instrument_app(app)
```

When FlaskInstrumentor().instrument_app(app) is run I get ther error: get_tracer() takes 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given. If anyone has a solution or advice to troubleshoot it I would be very grateful. The stack looks like this:

```
  File "C:\Test_projects\flask_project\microblog\app\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    FlaskInstrumentor().instrument_app(app)
  File "C:\Users\Tom Work\.virtualenvs\flask_project-AbPFWuIL\lib\site-packages\opentelemetry\instrumentation\flask\__init__.py", line 338, in instrument_app
    tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__, __version__, tracer_provider)
  File "C:\Users\Tom Work\.virtualenvs\flask_project-AbPFWuIL\lib\site-packages\opentelemetry\trace\__init__.py", line 494, in get_tracer
    return tracer_provider.get_tracer(
TypeError: get_tracer() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: What does your pip freeze show? What is the version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with clashing versions among my dependencies. I solved this by running `pipenv graph` and seeing that opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask required a different version of opentelemetry-api than I had. I uninstalled opentelemetry-api and opentelemetry-sdk and reinstalled them using the correct version and this problem was solved.